# How to draw rotated element as backgorund in HTML

Tags: html, css

I wonder how to draw a rotated element and set it as background? I was thinking about creating the element, for example a `div` and in CSS with position absolute, and just rotate it, but there must be a smarter way for that.

Something like this, at full size in browser:

[image: something like this, at full size in browser]

Comment: Smarter than 'add and rotate'?! I don't think so. But even if, I'd first try to get it working like that. Not quite sure want you need from us, actually.

Comment: SVG is the usual answer in these situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve a similar result to the picture you provided, you can create three **`div`** elements, fix them and use the transform property in CSS:

```
.element {
    position: fixed;
    transform: rotate(10deg) skew(10deg); /* 10 is used as an example */
}
```

I would suggest, however, that you drew the image in an image editor and just set it as background to the **`body`**. There is no need to overcomplicate things.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will set it just as background-image.

Comment: I think that's your best bet @PawełSkawicki.